# Review Stalker Reloaded: A cross-site dashboard for reviews

Tags: script, review

#### About

Originally based *very* loosely on the [OBSOLETE - Review Stalker user script](https://stackapps.com/questions/4086/review-stalker-user-script), this script has been rewritten several times since then. Its purpose is to be a one-stop pinned tab, always checking for review opportunities on main and meta as aggressively as is useful between multiple sites you configure.

#### License

[Version 3 of the GPL](https://github.com/TuggyNE/ReviewStalkerReloaded/blob/master/LICENSE) or any later version.

#### Usage

Switching to this tab should only be necessary when you see that it has the site's usual favicon, and when you do switch, the review will already be loaded. If there's more than one review queue with items for you, the others will be loaded in new tabs (although there is an option to force loading all queues in a single tab sequentially). The script will avoid getting stuck on stale review items by waiting an hour (by default) and continuing with the next site in rotation; it will also continue rotation after 15 seconds once a queue is empty or you've reached your limit in it. Normal rotation timing is such that all sites are visited every 5 minutes by default. Every so often (roughly every hour, by default), the script will go through per-site meta queues as well.

For performance reasons, the script will recycle its tab every so often by opening a new tab and closing the old one. By default, this is every 500 page loads. On my somewhat creaky machine, this is fine; it's difficult to imagine needing to set it lower, but if you want to recycle only every 2000 or 5000, you can try that.

If you're not going to do reviews for a while, you can use the Pause button the script adds to avoid pulling in reviews you won't handle.

#### Screenshots

[image: RSR header with recycle count, meta cycle, and settings circled]
The red circle surrounds the meta cycle indicator; blue is for the tab history length and its progress toward recycling; greeny-teal is the Settings button. Not circled: the version info and pause button.

[image: RSR Settings dialog for 1.8.25]
These settings should be fairly self-explanatory, but any that could be confusing have a tooltip.

#### Installation

[Install Review Stalker Reloaded](https://github.com/TuggyNE/ReviewStalkerReloaded/raw/master/Review_Stalker_Reloaded.user.js).

Once installed, visit each of your usual review pages (`/review`) once in the order you wish the script to run through them. Then leave a tab open with one of them loaded and let it do its thing.

(To remove a site from the list, log out or open a private window so you don't have review privileges, then visit the review page from there.)

#### Known Issues

- Doesn't run on discuss.area51.
- Currently broken and unmaintained (at least by me).

#### Version History

Most of this is reflected to some degree in the [GitHub repository](https://github.com/TuggyNE/ReviewStalkerReloaded/) (converted from hg and filtered of commits to unrelated userscripts).

**v1.4.06**: First public release.
v1.4.07: Hide header on a site without review privileges, where it won't load pages anyway.
**v1.5.06**: Refactored and tweaked to allow SO more effectively as well as closing the tab leaks from having more than one queue available at a time.
v1.5.07: Bugfix.
v1.5.08: Don't auto-close tabs if they were opened with something other than the review page or a queue.
v1.5.12: Some meta-load bugfixes and changing default interval.
v1.5.13: Fixed some auto-close glitches.
v1.5.14: Another meta-open bugfix.
v1.5.15: Handling docs-beta merge in a somewhat less than graceful fashion.
v1.5.23: Handling site removals, empty additions, and dead sites more gracefully. Also, SO and MSO are considered separately, and includes are tweaked to fit better.
v1.5.24: Empty filtered queues are properly considered empty.
v1.5.26: Handle site removals and error pages still more gracefully.
**v1.6.11**: Proper config dialog with all current settings.
v1.6.25: Nice icon buttons.
v1.6.26: Typo fix.
v1.6.38: Show current list of sites in Settings; more consistent timing.
v1.6.41: Avoid opening duplicate tabs.
v1.6.42: Quick fix for SE's TLS switchover on child metas. (Expect another fix when the domain scheme changes in 6-8 weeks.)
**v1.7.02**: Allow ignoring certain queues on certain sites.
v1.7.05: Clean up a few minor corner cases with Docs and spurious alerts.
**v1.8.25**: Option to force all queues to open in the same tab.
v1.8.28: No more special-casing for SO/MSO; staleness check resets after queue actions; fixed glitch with empty queue sometimes reloading repeatedly.
v1.8.32: Fixed site-meta handling for new meta scheme.
v1.8.33: One more bugfix for compat.
v1.8.49: Lots of assorted bugfixes.
v1.8.51: ru/pt/es SO subdomain support.
**v1.9.00**: Handle HTTPS more correctly, ignore history pages and ignored queues better, allow turning off recycling, upgrade FontAwesome, handle various error states better.
v1.9.01: Fixed regression on ru/pt/es SO metas.
v1.9.04: Modified to work on new responsive /review layout.
v1.9.06: Some stale bugfixes from before I stopped working on it.

Comment: For me, it doesn't work for http://meta.stackoverflow.com/review - it will redirect me to `http://review` if it is the first site I add; otherwise, it will redirect automatically to the first added site. FF 47.0.1 on Mac, with Greasemonkey.

Comment: @Glorfindel, thanks for the report! I'll dig into that as soon as I can.

Comment: @Glorfindel: I believe I've gotten the script to do what it should be doing in all cases (sending you through the list of sites as available, and never haring off in random directions, nor treating MSO as a site meta).

Comment: I'm having trouble connecting to your web server, is your script available elsewhere in any repository?

Comment: @JohnB: Unfortunately, no, but the site is back up.

Comment: @Gallifreyan: OK, strike those last, I've bit the bullet at last and implemented a proper options dialog.

Comment: Is it ok that the app opens a heck of a lot of review tabs? I left one tab open, and 15 minutes later there were 20. Which setting is this related to?

Comment: @Gallifreyan: Fixed now. ;)

Comment: Is there a way I can configure this to ignore a specific type of review queue (e.g. close votes)? Also it generates multiple tabs which are not pinned; I don't know if this is intentional

Comment: @suomynonA: Not yet. I can look into what that would take, though.

Comment: Maybe that wouldn't allow the script to redirect to  `/^https?://[^\.]*\.?whatever\.stackexchange\.com/review/close*` ? Don't know how to write that

Comment: @suomynonA: I think what I ended up with is pretty decent; enter plain *domain*/review/*queue* (e.g. `ell.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts`) in a comma-separated list and it will leave those out of its auto-navigation. (By the way, the extra tabs are intentional, or at least quite difficult to avoid in a way that's desirable, but I'm working on a possibility for cutting those down further.)

Comment: @suomynonA: New option to suppress any new tabs (except recycling the pinned tab, of course).

Comment: @NathanTuggy could you have a look at how the script handles the meta sites (since the HTTPS switch, they're at `*.meta.stackexchange.com` instead of `meta.*.stackexchange.com`) please?

Comment: Oh, and the SSL certificate from your website seems to have been revoked.

Comment: @Glorfindel: Oh, thanks for letting me know. Think the fix is out, and I'll work on SSL shortly. (Irritating StartSSL problems.)

Comment: Hmm ... with the new version, the script only seems to work on Meta SE, not on other (main or meta) sites. I can see GreaseMonkey loads it, but I don't see the "Review Stalker Reloaded v1.8.30" and the statistics.

Comment: I was on version 1.5.x before, so it's not something introduced in the latest update.

Comment: @Glorfindel: There seems to have been a bit of a glitch there; it should be on 1.8.32, not 1.8.30, so try that?

Comment: That was the version offered by the HTTP version of your website. I downloaded 1.8.32 via Safari and applied it manually, but that doesn't make a difference :(

Comment: @Glorfindel: Hmm. Can you check what sites it reports in its site list by opening the Options dialog on the one site you do have access to?

Comment: Under 'Current sites', nothing but `meta.stackexchange.com`.

Comment: @Glorfindel: OK, do you get any errors in the console when loading other sites?

Comment: Nope. Additional information: this happens in Firefox on macOS. I tested Chrome on Windows (with TamperMonkey) and there it works.

Comment: @Glorfindel: That's very puzzling. Mind trying a [debug build with `alert`s](http://www.tuggycomputer.com/nathan/software/userscripts/Review_Stalker_Reloaded_debug.user.js)?

Comment: I get a download error: `Error download URL: https://openuserjs.org/src/libs/sizzle/GM_config.js  Server returned 429 Too Many Requests` ...

Comment: @Glorfindel: That appears to be a backoff on that host's side; [should clear up in time](https://openuserjs.org/scripts/shush/Shush_Extension/issues/429_cant_install_1), but might be caused by an outdated and over-eager updater? (Probably not directly related to the main problem, though.) I've uploaded a copy that should let it work for now, though.

Comment: I installed it, but no alerts appear.

Comment: @NathanTuggy I think I found it. Firefox doesn't like this line: `var BChildMeta = BHasChildMeta(DomMain) && DomMain.contains("meta.");` because it doesn't support `contains` on strings. If I use `indexOf ... !== -1`, it works fine.

Comment: @Glorfindel: Oh, great! Thanks for the debug work on that, which saved me some more digging; that's recently added code, which explains the problem.

Comment: You're welcome. I'm happy to contribute *something* to a script I use often.

Comment: The review stalker no longer refreshes itself for me... Using chrome

Comment: @suomynonA: Are you getting any errors in the console? What sites are listed in the settings?

Comment: Pretty much all sites are there in the settings, and the lines with errors are 158 and 441, it says they're missing semicolons

Comment: @suomynonA: Try updating, and if it doesn't work let me know what sites you have specifically in settings, and whether you're using the single-tab-forcing.

Comment: Here are all the "include" and "exclude" lines: `// @include     *://*.stackexchange.com/review*
// @include     /^https?://[^\.]*\.?stackoverflow\.com/review/
// @include     /^https?://[^\.]*\.?serverfault\.com/review/
// @include     /^https?://[^\.]*\.?superuser\.com/review/
// @include     /^https?://[^\.]*\.?askubuntu\.com/review/
// @include     /^https?://[^\.]*\.?mathoverflow\.net/review/
// @include     *://stackapps.net/review/*
// @exclude     //stats$/` I'm not using the single-tab forcing.

Comment: @suomynonA: Oh, I mean the site list (the ones the script will actually run through) in the second section of the settings dialog, not the include rules.

Comment: The review stalker reloaded icons no longer show up; but it still can open review queues when I refresh the page...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55805/discussion-between-nathan-tuggy-and-suomynona).

Comment: Can you make it possible to review a site without reviewing its meta? For sites such as stackoverflow and puzzling.se I can review on the main site but not the meta site, and this causes some problems in the script.

Comment: @suomynonA: That's strange. There's long been a check specifically to avoid messing with e.g. the site list if it's running on a child meta, so if you go to MSO with <2000 rep it should just move on to the next after a while without any problems. What exactly is going wrong? Is it opening something, getting stuck without headers, getting stuck with headers, removing the site?

Comment: @NathanTuggy It's going to the meta and getting stuck, also saying that some other site is missing. If I close the tab and use a new one, the site is removed and sometimes the ui doesn't show up...

Comment: @suomynonA: Which site does it say is missing, and which one does it remove? I.e., does it remove SO when on MSO and then skip SO and MSO until they're readded, or is it a different site entirely? (Try setting meta load frequency to 1 or 2 in settings to make testing easier.)

Comment: @NathanTuggy It's different every time... right now the ui just disappears completely when on MSO. Apparently last time SO removed puzzling, which i also can't review meta for

Comment: @suomynonA: Are you running the script in multiple tabs by mistake? The tabs it opens by itself should be fine, as they close themselves instead of loading more /review, but otherwise, having two instances of the script loading /review almost simultaneously could easily cause this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56517/discussion-between-suomynona-and-nathan-tuggy).

Comment: Is there a change history avaliable, something like github?

Comment: @0xdb: Unfortunately, no; when I started writing the script, I didn't bother putting it in version control (as I didn't expect it to get so thorough), and then it was always kind of off-putting to contemplate shoving only the most recent version into a fresh repository. Perhaps I should anyway.

Comment: Yes, I think so. Maybe as the first step, you could put some few older versions in your repository (e.g. "old" folder).

Comment: For some reason this has always given me issues. When I first go to `/review` then RSR will open up a queue that is not on my ignore list, however during my reviews it will open up a queue that is on my ignore list. Nothing in console.

Comment: @K.Dᴀᴠɪs: So, if you go to /review with `stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts` in the ignore list, it won't open it the first time, and will come back around to automatically load /review again, but this time it will open LQP? Do you have "Load all reviews in same tab sequentially" set?

Comment: @NathanTuggy My process is that I go to `https://stackoverflow.com/review` first, and the RSR will automatically select a queue not in my ignore list, such as H&I. Then after a couple of reviews, it will automatically navigate to `/review/close` (which is on ignore because I save those for before the end of day to conserve votes). I do not have that option checked (everything is set to default except the ignore lists).

Comment: @K.Dᴀᴠɪs: Okay, so you load /review/close yourself from time to time? I'm going to have to add more code to handle that case properly; current script assumptions are that an ignored queue is *ignored*, as in "dead to me". But that does sound like a decent use case.

Comment: Oh - so was I misunderstanding the Ignored queue lists? So the intended use for that is RSR is inactive when I am in the ignored queue, but it will open _any queues_ when I am an an 'un-ignored' queue - regardless if that queue is on my ignore list?

Comment: @K.Dᴀᴠɪs: More specifically, if you ever open a queue, it will try to bring you back there. "Ignoring" means RSR won't open it from /review, but it has a separate stack of review items that haven't been finished. (Finishing out 20 or 40 items in a queue would typically clear it out for the next day, but that's not always going to happen.) It's less about intended use and more about minimal functional code, but that seems to have bitten me.

Comment: @K.Dᴀᴠɪs: The fix is pretty simple but the versioning has gotten jammed up, so I'll go through and sort that out tomorrow. (If you want to have a quick fix, find `let ResId = /\/(\d+)$/.exec(location.href);` in the `CheckQueueStatus` function and add `if (!QueueFromUrl(location.href)) {
    MarkQueueFinished();
  }
  else ` before the next line, `if (status) {`.)

Comment: So what I think may have happened was that on this particular PC, I didn't have anything in my ignore list. So it probably did initially open a `/close` review before I updated my ignore list - so it's probably taking me back to that particular review then? After today, this shouldn't be an issue after that item expires then?

Comment: @K.Dᴀᴠɪs: Yeah, it should clear it out as soon as the specific review item (`/review/close/NNNN`) is handled or invalidated and then auto-loaded. But from some experience of mis-inserted items that can be quite irritating in the meantime.

Comment: @K.Dᴀᴠɪs: Took a bit, but the script is finally updated. As a bonus there are a number of improvements that had gotten piled up in local testing....

Comment: Nathan Tuggy, in 1.9.0 Review Stalker Reloaded stopped working for me for Meta of Russian stack Overflow — **https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/review**. I can't see [**RSR icons**](https://i.imgur.com/qxirzOv.png) on Russian Meta. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Something caused it for me to keep opening "first posts", even when it's empty. It also doesn't go back to the overview. Reinstalling did not fix it, factory reset and then setting all settings again did fix it.

I definitely did complicated things with it, like restarting Chrome with a review tab open, Windows hibernation, pausing and resuming the script in different states, etc. Will update this if it happens again and I can narrow down the cause.

Comment: It happened again. It seems that when I set "Seconds between checks to move on from an empty queue" to 0, it constantly reloads any review item (<1s) and if I set it to a positive number, it opens "first posts" all the time.

Comment: Does it open first posts constantly, or just whenever it reloads on its usual schedule? What happens if you go to the overview page yourself before it reloads? Or if that's normally what you do, what happens if you wait it out?

Comment: Also, do you have a filter set on First Posts? The script has no logic to detect a queue with items that are all filtered out, so it will just load it every pass, then move on as normal when it finds it empty.

Comment: Opens first posts constantly. My schedule is set to 9 seconds and it's hard to even hit the configuration button. Clicking manually also doesn't help. No filter.

Answer (score 1):

## feature_request(customization): ignoring specific types of review

---

### 1. Summary

It would be nice, if would be option — ignore some types of review.

---

### 2. Argumentation

1. user can have gold badges for some review types and doesn't have badges for another types
2. user can more prefer some types of review, than others

---

### 3. Example

I want to ignore `Close Votes` and `Low Quality Posts`:

*(Sorry for Russian, I have high reputation only for Russian Stack Overflow)*

[image: Ignore examples]

---

### 4. Do not offer

1. Please, do not offer, that user must check all review types, even those in which user has gold badges. Users may want some benefit to themselves, not just the community.

Comment: Already exists: open settings, type the queue URL snippets into the "Queues to ignore" box separated by commas (e.g., `ru.stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts,ru.stackoverflow.com/review/close`).

Comment: @NathanTuggy, **status: not fixed for me**. I paste your text → `Save` → I get popup `List of review queues is invalid!` →  I still get posts with unexpected review types. [**Demonstration**](https://i.imgur.com/qhqiXRh.png). Firefox Quantum 59.0.2 (64-bit), Tampermonkey 4.6.5757, Review Stalker Reloader 1.8.49. Thanks.

Comment: OK, try installing the latest script version that I just uploaded and try again; ru/pt/es SO versions weren't well-supported (and in fact may still have bugs, I'm not sure).

Comment: @NathanTuggy, **status: another problem for me**. I open **https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/review** → this page reload 12 times → **https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/review** open → Review Stalker Reloaded doesn't work for **https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/review**. [**my settings**](https://i.imgur.com/VG46jSu.png). Previous problem fixed for me in 1.8.50. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry for the delay; 1.8.51 should fix this by generating ru/pt/es meta URLs better.

Comment: @NathanTuggy, **status: not fixed for me** in 1.8.51. Same problem as in my previous comment. Thanks.

Comment: Another long delay for no good reason, but I think 1.8.52 may fix the basic issue. Unfortunately, looking at the script in more depth also shows me that there will likely be all manner of other problems in regular use, given the amount of plain-text sniffing the script does that will break with Russian error/info messages. If you want to, you can edit the script to fill in the right messages; you'll need to edit the functions BCapped (out of reviews for the day), BEmpty (nothing in the queue for you), and BProcessed (this review entry has already been finished as far as you're concerned).

Comment: @NathanTuggy, **Status: Another problem for me** in 1.8.52 — open unexpected tabs. **Steps to reproduce** I enable Review Stalker Reloader → I open **https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review page** → page refresh → I get, for example, new first post. **Expected behavior** Open 1 tab with first post. **Actual behavior** Open 2 tabs: [**expected, with first post of new user**](https://i.imgur.com/rLEnXTN.png) and [**unexpected — “queues ended”**](https://i.imgur.com/4C9f4el.png). [**my configuration**](https://i.imgur.com/Q0HKyCg.png). Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I can't review ignored queues or check the status of any queue by clicking "Recent reviews".
If I try to choose an ignored queue, no matter how - in the same tab or in a new tab, after a timeout occurs I will be returned to the main review page or the new tab will be closed. The same happens if I'm trying to check a queue status.

Is this behavior a bug or a feature?

Before the current release I used the following fix (e.g. in 1.8.52):

```
function CheckQueueStatus() {
  let status = document.querySelector("div.review-status");
  let instr = document.querySelector("span.review-instructions.infobox");
  let ResId = /\/(\d+)$/.exec(location.href);
  if (status) {
    MarkQueueFinished(function () { document.title = TitleBase; })
    BPaused = true; // here my fix
  }
  else if ...
```

This fix isn't working after upgrading to the current 1.9.04 release anymore.

Comment: Both are bugs. I can't repro at the moment, but I'll check this out more tonight when I have time.

Comment: Thank you, it's not urgent, take the time to check the issues.

Comment: `/stats$` is in the script's exclusions (and therefore it should never even run on those pages), so either that somehow got overridden in user-custom inclusions, or else your userscript manager doesn't support the exclusion syntax. What browser and addon are you using? (Still looking into ignored queues.)

Comment: Chrome + Tampermonkey

Answer (score 1):

The [new changes to the review queues](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/360198/355458), now live across the network, have completely broken the script. It now no longer:

- Refreshes the page automatically
- Automatically opens any queues with pending reviews
- Switches to meta sites regularly
- Has any visual indicator on the review queues:

[image]

Comment: Note: I believe this can be fixed by replacing `.fs-subheading` with `.fs-body3` and the `:not(.oxx)` (the `x`s were numbers but I forgot which) with `.mb2`. There might be other things broken but it seems to be functioning so far after I've made those changes.

Comment: @RedwolfPrograms I think it's `:not(.030)`. Should one replace the whole thing with `.mb2` or just the `:not` part or just the `.oxx` part?

Comment: @user Just the `.o30`, so it should be `:not(.mb2)`

Answer (score 0):

The "recycle tab" feature seems to be broken. It opens a new tab, but it doesn't close the old one. This leads to an exponential growth in the number of tabs until at some point StackExchange's rate limit stops it. At that point, the script of course doesn't work at all anymore.

Comment: Hmm, never seen this. What browser are you using?

Comment: Chrome on Windows 7. A relatively new version (if it didn't update itself, a few weeks old).

Comment: Sorry about this: I somehow forgot to come back and let you know when I added a feature to help cope with this better. Current version allows you to set the recycle number to -1 to disable recycling in userscript managers that don't remember that the original tab was script-opened and forbid closing it.